# Adding a vertical UIScrollView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm not making progress on this problem for a while now.

I'm trying to add a vertical scroll view to my app with a contentView (UIView). I added the contentView as a subview of the scrollView & added the scrollView as a subview of the main view. After that, I wasn't able to scroll and buttons + the searchbar weren't working anymore. It just felt like the app was frozen.

What I've done so far is the following:

**Creating the scroll- and contentView directly in the class**

```
let scrollView:UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
let contentView:UIView = UIView()
```

**Setting up the scrollView**

```
 func setupScrollView() {
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    
    // Add scroll view to main view
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    
    // Add content to scrollview
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    
    // Constraints
    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

**Adding several elements as subview to the contentView**

```
// Add search bar to scroll content view
contentView.addSubview(searchBar)
```

The full code is available [on my github repo](https://github.com/timlangner/chayns-ios-clone/blob/main/chayns-ios-clone/ViewController.swift)

I looked through several similar problems and tutorials but somehow can't figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: You're basically setting your scrollview's `contentSize` the same as its actual size, which means there's nothing to scroll. If you want to scroll vertically, make `contentSize.height` larger than scrollview's frame size. Also, you're not supposed to add contentView-scrollView contraints - you can't scroll something that is set to be at fixed position. Also, you're adding way to many contraints - if you have `leading` and `trailing` then you don't need `centerX` or `width`.

Comment: That makes sense.. Thanks for your great answer!